# What tools auto-populate a floorplan with measurements?

Tags: planning

I have a home floorplan that I want to add measurements too. Assuming I have an initial scale (like X" on paper = Y' feet in real-life), are there tools (apps or websites) that can auto-populate my floorplan with measurements?

Comment: If you do the drawing in a CAD program, or import it into one, you can generally set the scale "by example". Once that's done, assuming the drawing was to scale in the first place, everything can be read out of the program. Or are you specifically looking for insertion of size labels in the printout?

Comment: The CAD program is a great suggestion. However, I would like insertion of size labels as well when printed.

Comment: @Craig - The whole idea of using a capable CAD program that has dimensioning is that you add the dimension objects to the drawing and they remain there at time of printing. Some more capable CAD programs support the concepts of "layers". You can put all dimensions on a specific layer and then select if that layer shows at print time or not.  Note that a very capable FREE CAD program is called DraftSight. Search for it and download it. It works very much like the 2D version of AutoCad except it is FREE - you just have to register it to use it.